# Why can a variable of one class point to a different class with the same content?

Tags: typescript, class

Why I can do this in TypeScript?

```
class Cat { }

class Dog { }

let dog: Dog = new Cat();
```

It's wrong in languages like Java, C# and C++.

Comment: You haven't actually typed `cat`, so it's inferred as a `Dog`. Why *wouldn't* this be allowed? The TS compiler won't make assumptions based on just the identifier.

Comment: hi, sry, i pasted the wrong code, now its correct, can you pls read the question again.

Comment: You should read up on the difference between *structural* and *nominal* typing systems. TS is structural and your two classes have the same interface, so anything expecting one can receive the other just fine.

Comment: ahh, thanks, thats explains a lot.
https://medium.com/@thejameskyle/type-systems-structural-vs-nominal-typing-explained-56511dd969f4

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ

Comment: its also explained in the typescript handbook but it comes after classes section.